# Write Remarks from last to first remark in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me in solving the below problem.

| Event_id | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| 1245 | "01/12/21 16:14 od03: Rectification time.01/12/21 16:28 od02: Fused |
| 1252 | "01/12/21 01:14 od01: visible.01/12/21 02:28 od04:I am updating.01/12/21 02:28 od03: kindly see the issue" |

Multiple people giving remark we have to arrange it from last remark to first remark in output. Every new remark is starting with some "DATE TIME OD00:"

**Expected Output:-**

| Event_id | Remarks |
| --- | --- |
| 1245 | "01/12/21 16:28 od02: Fused.01/12/21 16:14 od03: Rectification time. |
| 1252 | "01/12/21 02:28 od03: kindly see the issue.01/12/21 02:28 od04:I am updating.01/12/21 01:14 od01: visible" |

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using

Comment: Wrong data model. REMARKS should be a separate table with a foreign key pointing to EVENTS. REMARKS should then have the DATE datatype column and TEXT column (to put actual remark into it). **Then** you shouldn't have such a problem.

Comment: You really want to rearrange the characters in the string?  Why are the remarks concatenated to each other like that?  Why aren't they stored in separate rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   my_table
order by 
  to_date(substr(remarks,1,14),'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi'),
  substr(remarks,16,4),
  event_id
```

should get you started, but obviously you need a lot of confidence in that quality of the data in that REMARKS column.